# How to get WASD movement on FPS mapped to xbox controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller

i am trying to create a simple game with an FPS controller.How do i get the WASD keys on the keyboard to work on the controller? Do i have to change the script ?I found a sample project on github.But there seems to be a lot of coding involved.Also im using the Gvr so,i want my character to move forward according to the GVR.
Thanks

Comment: Go to Edit->Project Settings -> Input and look for Horizontal and Vertical Axis. Map axis according to XBox buttons. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Xbox360Controller

Comment: Will this work for android too ? So i have to change the "horizontal" to joystick movement and x axis..Okay.Will try it out

Comment: I didn't try it by myself but It should work :)

Comment: @UmairM: Hi , i'd consider it a big favor if you would answer another question of mine.Its something to do with the script,so please ? Here s a link to the question                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464228/can-anybody-tell-me-what-is-wrong-in-this-script     . Thank you so much