# Why this script seems to work only with the first joystick input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

This program is supposed to move my character forward when there is a positive offset in the Y direction of the joystick and stop moveing when the joystick isn't moving. But my code seems to do that only for the first time. The second time onward, it seems to stop moving when I press the button and moves when I release it.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class move : MonoBehaviour {
  public Transform obj;
  float threshold = 0.0f;   
  Vector3 current_pos;

  void Start () {
    current_pos = obj.position;
  } 

  public void Update() {
    Vector3 offset = obj.position - current_pos; 
    if(offset.y > threshold) { // goes forward
      transform.Translate(Vector3.forward *10* Time.deltaTime);
      transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (offset.y < threshold){ // goes reverse
      transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward *10* Time.deltaTime);
      transform.Translate(Vector3.up *10* Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
  }
}
```

I have a small sphere to which the joystick input is given. And I'm making my character move if there is a positive movement in the sphere's position(offset).
So if the sphere moves forward (owing to the joystick input) my character moves. But my character moves continuoslt just after a single movement. Doesn't stop.

Comment: Have you heard of debugging? It is about running your application step by step and you can check whether all the values match to your expectation.

Comment: why aren't you updating the current position in your update function? Your if statement in your start function should - as i understand it - always return false because current position is the object position and the difference between the two should be zero.

Comment: Also, anything times zero is always zero - though I assume you know that. I say that because `transform.Translate(Vector3.up *0* Time.deltaTime, Space.World);` and the line above it both multiply by zero. A typo maybe? or on purpose? because you're transforming by zero.

Comment: I guess if i update the current position,then there wont be an offset, is there ? Because say the normal position of the joystick is (0,0,0) and the obj.position is what changes constantly.Atleast that what i want in the program. :/

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve with this code. Update your question with elaboration of what you want to do in the end

Comment: your threshold is 0.0f but your offset.y will never be 0.0f again after it moved even just a little. so alter threshold value. also try debug.log values when you have an issue to help yourself (it would also be nice not doing " *10* " but instead " * 10 * " if you want to help those who'll read your code in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in your code are you pulling user input.

```
//getting the x axis from a controller
var v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

//getting the y axis from a controller
var h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
```

From here you can apply the values of v and\or h for your movement code.

```
public void Update() {
    var h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Vector3 offset = obj.position - current_pos; 
    if(h > threshold) { // goes forward
      transform.Translate(Vector3.forward *10* Time.deltaTime);
      transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (h < threshold){ // goes reverse
      transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward *10* Time.deltaTime);
      transform.Translate(Vector3.up *10* Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
  }
```

You can take this a step further if you were wanting to use a `rigidbody2d`

```
private void CheckInput()
{

  //getting the y axis from a controller
  var h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
  var moveVector = new Vector2(h*Speed, 0);
  Vector3 offset = obj.position - current_pos; 
  PlayerRigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(moveVector.x, moveVector.y);

}
```

an alternative is to apply a force to a rigid body

```
public bool facingRight = true;
public float moveForce = 365f;          // Amount of force added to move the player left and right.
public float maxSpeed = 5f;             // The fastest the player can travel in the x axis.


void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Cache the horizontal input.
    float h = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    // The Speed animator parameter is set to the absolute value of the horizontal input.
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (h));

    // If the player is changing direction (h has a different sign to velocity.x) or hasn't reached maxSpeed yet...
    if (h * rigidbody2D.velocity.x < maxSpeed)
    {
        // ... add a force to the player.
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (Vector2.right * h * moveForce);
    }

    // If the player's horizontal velocity is greater than the maxSpeed...
    if (Mathf.Abs (rigidbody2D.velocity.x) > maxSpeed)
    {
        // ... set the player's velocity to the maxSpeed in the x axis.
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (Mathf.Sign (rigidbody2D.velocity.x) * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }

    // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
    if (h > 0 && !facingRight)
    {
        // ... flip the player.
        Flip ();
    }
    else if (h < 0 && facingRight) // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
    {
        // ... flip the player.
        Flip ();
    }
}


void Flip ()
{
    //Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
    facingRight = !facingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

[Detailed version of this Example](http://hackerferret.com/uncategorized/playing-with-unity3d-and-the-4-3-2d-tools/)

For a more detailed bit of code for handling vertical and horizontal movement from device input I have an [open sourced game jam game](https://github.com/musicm122/The-Depths-of-H-E-double-hockey-stick/blob/master/Assets/Game/Scripts/Player/PlayerControls.cs) I did a while back. Also, I have a few [code examples](http://hackerferret.com/portfolio/)

Comment: Hi I tried with your code too.My actual problem is that the gameobject moves even with no inout from the joystick.The first time the app opens, it waits for the positive input and then moves continuosly.

Comment: Could you show me what your updated code looks like?

Comment: Thanks Terrance.I guess it works fine with the rigid body movement :).